# AS3 Loop Animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

I have created a image rotating banner in AS3 which basically FadesIn and FadesOut in continuous loop. I want the banner to loop 3 times and then stop, I am having a hard time to make it stop after 3 loops. Well I am very new to AS3. Here's the code below. Please Help!!

Thank you!!

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

mc1.alpha = 0;
mc2.alpha = 0;
mc3.alpha = 0;
var counter;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,9);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerListener);
timer.start();

function timerListener(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    if (timer.currentCount == 1){

    if (counter==1){ var tween6:Tween = new Tween(mc3,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true)}// fade out routine over 1 sec
    var tween1:Tween = new Tween(mc1,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,2,true)// fade in routine over 2 seconds

}


if (timer.currentCount == 4)
{
    var tween2:Tween = new Tween(mc1,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);//  fade out routine
    var tween3:Tween = new Tween(mc2,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,2,true);//fade in routine
}

if (timer.currentCount == 7)
{
    var tween4:Tween = new Tween(mc2,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);//  fade out routine
    var tween5:Tween = new Tween(mc3,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,2,true);// fade in routine

}

if (timer.currentCount == 9)//reset routine
    {
    counter = 1;
    timer.reset();
    timer.start();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to do this; however, it looks like you have a `counter` object already in place; so, let's use that.

You rely on the timer's `currentCount` to determine which slide and animation to play.

When `timer.currentCount` reaches 9, you set `counter` to 1.

```
if (timer.currentCount == 9) {
    counter = 1;
```

Instead of setting it to 1, increment it so that each pass its value will increase.

```
if (timer.currentCount == 9) {
    counter++;
```

Then, when `counter` is equals to 3, do not start the timer.

To highlight the relevant code:

```
// initialize your counter
var counter = 0;

/* ... */

if (timer.currentCount == 9) {
    counter++;
    timer.reset();

    if (counter < 3)
        timer.start();
}
```